# dataTableBundle - turn on 'individual_filtering' for specific columns only

Tags: php, symfony, datatable

I'm using  [`stwe/datataTablebundle`](https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle) for my symfony application. I'd like to have individual column filters on some specific columns, but setting `'individual_filterting' => true` turns on the filter for every column. How to I specify columns? Currently I am hiding unwanted columns using css.

```
    $this->options->set(array(
        'display_start' => 0,
        'defer_loading' => -1,
        'dom' => 'lfiprtip',
        'length_menu' => array(20, 50, 100, 1000, 10000, '"All"'),
        'order_classes' => true,
        'order' => array(array(0, 'asc')),
        'order_multi' => true,
        'page_length' => 50,
        'paging_type' => Style::FULL_NUMBERS_PAGINATION,
        'renderer' => '',
        'scroll_collapse' => false,
        'search_delay' => 0,
        'state_duration' => 7200,
        'stripe_classes' => array(),
        'class' => Style::BOOTSTRAP_3_STYLE . ' table-condensed',
        'individual_filtering' =>false,
        'individual_filtering_position' => 'head',
        'use_integration_options' => true,
        'force_dom' => true,
    ));
```